# Redis Spring Data message listener for mykey with generic command filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to add a specific pattern for my key in Redis spring data listener but it's not working. How can I achieve the listener only for a specific command? Below is my message listener container:

```
@Bean
public RedisMessageListenerContainer redisMessageListenerContainer(
            RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MyMessageListener myMessageListener) {
        RedisMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        listenerContainer.addMessageListener(myMessageListener,
                   new PatternTopic("__keyspace@*__:SampleProj:Message:*")); 
            return listenerContainer;
        }
```

The above pattern works fine and I can get all the event messages in my `messageListener` class, like all events: del, hset etc. Now I need to get the only the hset events for mykey and I followed the commands as mentioned in [the docs](https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/) and didn't succeed. Below are the patterns I tried:

```
new PatternTopic("__keyevent*:hset SampleProj:Message:*")
new PatternTopic("__keyevent@*__:hset:SampleProj:Message:*"));
new PatternTopic("__keyevent@*__:hset SampleProj:Message:*"));
```

Even with combined list:

```
Arrays.asList(new PatternTopic("__keyevent@*__:hset SampleProj:Message:"),
new PatternTopic("__keyspace@*__:SampleProj:Message:* hset")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are missing here.... You cant directly filter the command type in pattern string, instead you have to capture al the events and then filter as per your need in your 'MyMessageListener' implementation.

Here is how you can achieve it.

```
@Bean
public RedisMessageListenerContainer redisMessageListenerContainer(
        RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        MyMessageListener myMessageListener) {
    RedisMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    // Listen to all key events
    PatternTopic patternTopic = new PatternTopic("__keyevent@*__:*");
    listenerContainer.addMessageListener(myMessageListener, patternTopic);

    return listenerContainer;
}
```

As you can see here we are listening to all the key events. Now in 'MyMessageListener' we will do the filtering part as shown below.

```
public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
        String channel = new String(message.getChannel());
        String key = new String(message.getBody());

        if (channel.startsWith("__keyevent@") && channel.endsWith("__:hset")) {
            // Handle hset event for your key
            System.out.println("Received hset event for key: " + key);
        }

        // Handle other cases if needed
    }
}
```

This is how you can filter events in your 'onMessage' method based on the channel name.

I hope i made myself clear and added some value.
Best of luck on your coding adventures!